# Python: List printing __main__.Node object at 0x102377f98

Tags: python

The output for my string list is a node object instead of a normal output like [1,2,3], how do i fix this?

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, item, link):
        self.item = item
        self.next = link

    def __str__(self):

        string = []
        item = self.top
        while item is not None:
            string.append(str(item))
            item = item.next
        return str(string)
```

Comment: Also see [Difference between \_\_str\_\_ and \_\_repr\_\_ in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1436703)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hmm I think I like that better as a canonical duplicate, bookmarked!

Comment: @CoryKramer: I was just thinking that your dupe target here was great for this specific case. :-)